# Using the Verse Package and Line Numbering

Tags: line-breaking, verse

Does anyone have a way to make line numbers show up only on the first part of the line using `verse`? A reduced example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{That the mountains may bring prosperity t\'o the p\'eople,}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\verselinenumbersleft
\poemlines{1}
I will bless the L\'ord at \'all times; *\\>
his praise shall e\underline{\textit{ver}} b\'e in m\'y mouth.\\!
I will gl\'ory \'in the Lord; *\\>
let the hum\underline{\textit{ble}} h\'ear and r\'ejoice.\\!
Proclaim with me the gr\'eatness \'of the Lord; *\\>
let us exalt \underline{his} n\'ame tog\'ether.\\!
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the verse numbers repeating on every line of a verse. I just want the first of each number to appear. I don't think I have any particular attachment to `verse` as the package to work with, so other routes might work better!

Answer (score 4):

The [`verse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/verse) redefines `\\` to condition on a number of options supplied after it. However, regardless of the choice, it always prints the number first.

We can intervene by redefining what `\\` does. Since `\\` is used in various other places (not just inside the `verse` environment) that package defines it elsewhere as part of `\@vscentercr`. The below redefinition moves the line-numbering portion to a place that provides your desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@vscentercr}{%
  \ifhmode \unskip\else \@nolnerr\fi
  \@vsifgt{\@vstypelinenum\verselinebreak}{%
    \incr@vsline
    \par\@ifstar{\nobreak\@vsxcentercr}{%
      \@vsifbang{\@ifnextchar[ {\@vsicentercr}{}}{\@vsxcentercr}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{That the mountains may bring prosperity t\'o the p\'eople,}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  \verselinenumbersleft
  \poemlines{1}
  I will bless the L\'ord at \'all times; *\\>
  his praise shall e\underline{\textit{ver}} b\'e in m\'y mouth.\\!
  I will gl\'ory \'in the Lord; *\\>
  let the hum\underline{\textit{ble}} h\'ear and r\'ejoice.\\!
  Proclaim with me the gr\'eatness \'of the Lord; *\\>
  let us exalt \underline{his} n\'ame tog\'ether.\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

The following [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch pair provides a similar redefinition of `\@vscentercr`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@vscentercr}{\@vstypelinenum}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@vscentercr}{\verselinebreak}{\@vstypelinenum\verselinebreak}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks - being something of a newbie at this who has forgotten most of the little coding I ever learnt! 

Is there a way of extending this further so that it can cope with verses that run over three or more lines? i.e. a block that looks like: `I will bless the Lord at all times; \\> his praise shall ever be in my mouth.\\>  I will glory in the Lord; \\!`